# Trying to keep the values of a form with velocity template

Tags: javascript, java, html, templates, velocity

So I am making a website and made a form to register an account. Everything that happens during the registration will get handled by the java/velocity part.

Within the registration U have to put your password twice and I already made a check to check those but, now whenever that doesn't happen I want to keep the values the user put in the fields.

Now my question is do I do this with js and if how? Or do I need to do something completely different?

```
<form action="" id="registerForm" method="post">
<h1>$msg.get("REGISTER_HEADING")</h1>
<p>$msg.get("REGISTER_INSTRUCTIONS")</p>

<div class ="test">
<label>$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_FIRSTNAME")</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_FIRSTNAME")" value="" required>
</div>

<label>$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_SURNAME")</label>

<div class = "test">
<input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_SURNAME")" value="" required><br>
</div>

<div class = "test2">
<label>$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_EMAIL")</label>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_EMAIL")" value="" required><br>
</div>


<div class ="test">
<label>$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_PASSWORD")</label>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_PASSWORD")" value="" required>
</div>

<div class ="test">
<label>$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_PASSWORD2")</label>
<input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_PASSWORD2")" value="" required><br>
</div>

<div class = "test2"
<label>$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_MPHONE")</label>
<input type="number" name="mobile" placeholder="$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_MPHONE")" value="" required><br>
</div>

<div class = "test2"
<label>$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_HPHONE")</label>
<input type="number" name="home" placeholder="$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_HPHONE")" value="" required><br>
</div>

<div class = "test2"
<label>$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_COUNTRY")</label>
<input type="text" name="country" placeholder="$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_COUNTRY")" value="" required><br>
</div>

<div class = "test2"
<label>$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_CITY")</label>
<input type="text" name="city" placeholder="$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_CITY")" value="" required><br>
</div>


<div class = "test2"
<label>$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_POSTALCODE")</label>
<input type="text" name="postal_code" placeholder="$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_POSTALCODE")" value="" required><br>
</div>

<div class = "test"
<label>$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_STREET")</label>
<input type="text" name="street" placeholder="$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_STREET")" value="" required><br>
</div>

<div class = "test"
<label>$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_HNUMBER")</label>
<input type="text" name="number" placeholder="$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_HNUMBER")" value="" required><br>
</div>

<input id="sign-up-submit" type="submit" value="$msg.get  ("REGISTER_BUTTON_REGISTER")">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery- latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/main.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for any javascript. You just need to store received values (for instance in a session attribute) so that they are available when rendering the form again.

Let say that you store POST parameters as a map, under the `register_params` session attribute name.

If you use Velocity Tools, then session attributes will be visible from inside the templates, otherwise you have an extra work of putting `register_params` in the Velocity context before the rendering.

Then in your template, you just have to do:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="$msg.get("REGISTER_LABEL_FIRSTNAME")" value="$!register_params.firstname" required>
```

Since `$!register_params.firstname` uses the *silent* notation, it won't display anything if it is null.